# Make div stick to top of page after scrolling past another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, header

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="sticky"></div>
<div id="section"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>

<style>
  body { margin: 0px; background-color: #e3e3e3; }
  #header { background-color: #cb5454; height: 140px; }
  #sticky { background-color: #546bcb; height: 70px; }
  #section { height: 1500px; }
  #footer { background-color: #cb5454; height: 140px; }
</style>
```

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/uaqh018d/

I want #sticky to stick to the top of the page after scrolling past #header. **I also want it hidden until stuck.** And then of course have it unstick+hide again after scrolling back up to #header.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would recommend adding a class to `#sticky` when it's ready to be fixed to the top of the screen, and then removing that class when you want to 'unstick' it. Then you can manipulate that class in CSS.

e.g. for a class `fixed` you'd put the following in your CSS:

```
#sticky {
    display: none;
    background-color: #546bcb;
    height: 70px;
}
#sticky.fixed {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And then your jQuery would look like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var distanceFromTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (distanceFromTop >= $('#header').height()) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Here's an updated [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uaqh018d/30/)

I might also recommend some jQuery fade or slide effects (see the fiddle).

Comment: Thank you! I believe this to be more efficient!

Comment: What is the height is dynamic and not known?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge You mean the height of the sticky header? http://jsfiddle.net/uaqh018d/40/

Comment: I keep getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scroll' of null`

Comment: the fade option in fiddle link make the menu disappear when scrolling back to top

Answer (score 5):

You can use `position: fixed` and in js detect when user scroll like this:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  //detect when user scroll to top and set position to relative else sets position to fixed
  $("#sticky").css({
    "top": "0",
    "position": $(this).scrollTop() > 140 ? "fixed" : "relative"
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
#header {
  background-color: #cb5454;
  height: 140px;
}
#sticky {
  background-color: #546bcb;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
#section {
  height: 1500px;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #cb5454;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="sticky"></div>
<div id="section"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**References**

[.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Comment: ALMOST. WE'RE SO CLOSE. I just need to have it unstick when you scroll back up to bottom of #header, not when you scroll up to the very top of page.

Comment: Oh, there we go! Your fiddle is working as it should now. Thanks man!

I had to accept bowheart's answer. It appears to be more efficient, but thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the div I wanted to be sticky was inside of another div (ie. not stuck to the page, but in another fixed div on the side of the page).  Here's my adaptation of @bowhart's answer to solving this problem given a React component (sticky_adapter.js):

```
module.exports.makeItSticky = function(thisReactComponent, parentScrollNode = window) {
  const thisNode = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(thisReactComponent));
  const position = thisNode.position();

  // Uncomment for verbose logging
  //console.log("Initial position: " + UIUtils.stringify(position));

  const scrollContainer = $(parentScrollNode);
  scrollContainer.scroll(() => {
    const distanceFromTop = scrollContainer.scrollTop();
    // Uncomment for verbose logging
    //console.log("ScrollTop: " + distanceFromTop);

    if (distanceFromTop > position.top) {
      thisNode.addClass("stick-to-top");
    } else {
      thisNode.removeClass("stick-to-top");
    }
  });
};
```

Now, to make any React component sticky, I just add to the class:

```
componentDidMount() {
  StickyAdapter.makeItSticky(this, ".some-other-div-which-is-the-container");
}
```

Finally, the css for the sticky class:

```
.stick-to-top {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is and old question but for new visitors I think u just need to add this css code to #sticky:

```
#sticky { position:sticky;top:0; }
```

and no need for javascript.

sticky toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position.

and don't forget that, the parent also should not have overflow property