# How do you make 2 separate divs take turns to stick at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to **make 2 divs sticky headers at the top** when the page is being scrolled.

The `FIRST DIV` gets to **stick** only for a while till the `SECOND DIV` appears at a particular point on the screen.

When the `SECOND DIV`, as it scrolls upwards, reaches half the page (for instance) the `FIRST DIV` stops being **sticky**, gets pushed away and then gets to be replaced by the `SECOND DIV` as the **next sticky element** at the top.

I managed to make first div stick to the top with my **CSS** but have no clue as to what do with the `second div`.

```css
.body {
  margin: 0;
}

h3 {
  background-color: #E9BDF5;
  width: 100%;
}

.firstDiv {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.secondDiv {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<h3>These text don't stick</h3>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and
</p>

<div class="firstDiv">
  <h2>First Div - Becomes sticky (temporarily)</h2>
</div>

<h3>These text don't stick</h3>

<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>

<div class="secondDiv">
  <h2>Second Div - Becomes the sticky header</h2>
</div>

<h3>These text don't stick</h3>

<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
```

Any advise on this would be most appreciated. I thank you in advance for your kind help ♥️

Comment: Can you show me how, please?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663602/make-div-stick-to-top-of-page-after-scrolling-past-another-div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use a wrapping div that acts as a boundary for the `position: sticky;`

```css
html {
  font-size: 150%;
}

.firstDiv,
.secondDiv {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h3>These text don't stick</h3>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
</p>
<p>
  This paragraph will scroll up and
</p>

<div>
  <div class="firstDiv">
    <h2>First Div - Becomes sticky (temporarily)</h2>
  </div>

  <h3>These text don't stick</h3>

  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="secondDiv">
    <h2>Second Div - Becomes the sticky header</h2>
  </div>

  <h3>These text don't stick</h3>

  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
  <p>
    This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Awww you're the best @christiansany. Simple and effective. Your solution just saved my problem. Thank you very much

Comment: Happy to help :D