# How to get sticky div to stop above sibling?

Tags: javascript, css

I have two containers that have two `divs` inside them each. I want the first `div` to stop at the top of the middle `div` and then the middle 'div' to stop at top of the the second 'div'.

I know that the stickiness of the child is the height of the container so it sticks all the way to the bottom but is there any way that I could get it to stop at its sibling? I can't change the the layout of the containers unfortunately. I would prefer CSS only but am open to JavaScript solutions.

I created this jsfiddle to better show the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/qm2a3vtw/5/

```css
html {
  font-size: 150%;
}

.firstDiv,
.secondDiv,
.middleDiv,
.middleDiv-2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.firstDiv {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 300px;
}

.secondDiv {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 450px;
  width: 80%;
}

.middleDiv {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
}

.middleDiv-2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
}

p {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='sidebar-container'>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="firstDiv">
      <h2>First Div</h2>
    </div>
    <p>
      This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
    </p>
    <p>
      This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
    </p>
    <p>
      This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
    </p>
    <div class="middleDiv">
      <h2>Middle Div </h2>
    </div>
    <p>
      This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-container-2">
    <div class="secondDiv">
      <h2>Second Div </h2>
    </div>
    <p>
      This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
    </p>
    <p>
      This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
    </p>
    <div class="middleDiv-2">
      <h2>Middle Div </h2>
    </div>
    <p>
      This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
    </p>
    <p>
      This paragraph will scroll up and will not stick at the top
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I tried to add another `div` to put the first `div` and middle `div` so that would be the parent and when the first child scrolled down it would stop at the next child but that didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify this line: "I want the first div to stop at the middle div and not at the bottom of the container."

Comment: @nvkrj I have edited it.

Comment: Is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71533756/15196112) answer your question?

Comment: @Fash I tried to add a div between the container and first div but that didn’t work

Comment: try this [link](https://codepen.io/lod/pen/YZdvgM)

Comment: @Fash unfortunately I'm not able to change the layout of the content

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.div-content {
  height: 100%;
}

.first-div {
  top: 0;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.second-div {
  top: 0;
  border: solid 2px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-1">
  <div class="sticky first-div">
    Container 1: First Div
  </div>
  <div class="sticky second-div">
    Container 1: Second Div
  </div>
  <div class="sticky emtpy-div"></div>
</div>
<div id="container-2">
  <div class="sticky first-div">
    Container 2: First Div
  </div>
  <div class="sticky second-div">
    Container 2: Second Div
  </div>
  <div class="sticky emtpy-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite. It looks like the first div is just hiding behind the second div but i would like it to stop at the top of the second div and not be shown again until you scroll back to the top. like this but with the first and second div being in the same container  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71533618/how-do-you-make-2-separate-divs-take-turns-to-stick-at-the-top-of-the-page

Comment: @bb8 I've updated the snippet above according to what I understand of your wording. Let me know if it works now!

Comment: It looks like it's the same problem that I'm facing. If you change the width of the second container to less than 100% you'll see that when you scroll down and get to the second div, the first div is still scrolling down with the second div instead of stopping